# What is this shrub with simple but attractive red flowers?

Tags: identification, shrubs

What is this shrub with simple but attractive red flowers?

The exact cultivar would be greately appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

There is another one of the same kind nearby, this time it is pruned to more regular shape:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny, someone else asked about one of these about a month ago. I think this also is a flowering quince, or Chaenomeles. They are very striking in the spring when they are in bloom, but pretty plain looking the rest of the year, so maybe that is why people are wondering about it this season?

Comment: Thanks, can you perhaps guess the exact cultivar?

Comment: But they may be very striking for birds in autumn and winter - I've heard the fruit attracts birds, no?